# Removing duplicate products from array

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I'm pulling all products from all orders made by a customer in Magento, I need to remove any duplicated products though, I guess I need to add another loop to the foreach($ordered_items as $item){ section to remove any duplicates but everything I try doesn't seem to work? Code below gets me all products from all orders made by logged in customer (there is a bit more but this is where I need to remove the duplicates)

```
foreach($collection as $order){

$order_id = $order->getId();

$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); //load order by order id 

$ordered_items = $order->getAllItems(); 

foreach($ordered_items as $item){     //item detail
```

FULL CODE IS

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

/* Get the customer data */
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
/* Get the customer's email address */
$customer_email = $customer->getEmail();

}

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email',array('like'=>$customer_email));

foreach($collection as $order){
//do something
$order_id = $order->getId();

$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); //load order by order id 

$ordered_items = $order->getAllItems(); 

foreach($ordered_items as $item){     //item detail  

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
$product_small_image_path = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200);
$product_thumbnail_path = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(150);
$summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
   ->load($item->getProductId());

echo "<li>";

echo "<div class='previous-name'><p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
echo $item->getName() ."</a></p></div>"; 

echo "<div class='previous-image'><a href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
echo "<img src='" . $product_small_image_path . "' />";
echo "</a></div>";

echo "<div class='previous-rating'>";
echo "<p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "#product_tabs_review_tabbed'>Review this beer now</a></p>"; 

echo $summaryData->getRatingSummary().'% Would buy again <br/>';

echo "<div class='rating-box' style='float:left;'>"; 
echo "<div class='rating' style='width:" .$summaryData->getRatingSummary()."%'></div></div>"; 
echo "</div>";

echo "<div class='previous-button'>";
echo '<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation(\'';
echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
echo '\')"><span><span>Order Again</span></span></button>';
echo "</div>";

echo "<div class='previous-clear'></div>";

echo "</li>";
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `array_unique()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another easy way to avoid extra foreach and PHP processing, Store product sku when taken inside foreach into an array and check if it is already in that array. Below if my modifications in your previous code :

```
<?php
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

    /* Get the customer data */
    $customer       = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    /* Get the customer's email address */
    $customer_email = $customer->getEmail();

}

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', array(
    'like' => $customer_email
));
$uniuqProductSkus = array();
foreach ($collection as $order) {
    //do something
    $order_id = $order->getId();

    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); //load order by order id 

    $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();

    // -----------------Initialized an empty array to store unique products SKUS

    foreach ($ordered_items as $item) {
     //item detail  
        //Check if product already exists  in uniuqProductSkus array, means it is duplicate, do not process, continue
        if (in_array($item->getProduct()->getSku(), $uniuqProductSkus)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            // product is not yet found, push  into the uniuqProductSkus array
            array_push($uniuqProductSkus, $item->getProduct()->getSku());
            $_product                 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $product_small_image_path = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200);
            $product_thumbnail_path   = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(150);
            $summaryData              = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->load($item->getProductId());

            echo "<li>";

            echo "<div class='previous-name'><p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
            echo $item->getName() . "</a></p></div>";

            echo "<div class='previous-image'><a href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
            echo "<img src='" . $product_small_image_path . "' />";
            echo "</a></div>";

            echo "<div class='previous-rating'>";
            echo "<p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "#product_tabs_review_tabbed'>Review this beer now</a></p>";

            echo $summaryData->getRatingSummary() . '% Would buy again <br/>';

            echo "<div class='rating-box' style='float:left;'>";
            echo "<div class='rating' style='width:" . $summaryData->getRatingSummary() . "%'></div></div>";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div class='previous-button'>";
            echo '<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation(\'';
            echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
            echo '\')"><span><span>Order Again</span></span></button>';
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div class='previous-clear'></div>";

            echo "</li>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you @blastfreak but I am still getting the duplicates I added var_dump($uniuqProductSkus); after the last echo and there are still lines like this twice array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "292" }

Comment: update: when I var_dump($uniuqProductSkus); after echo product data I get the following Product 1: array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "96" }  Product 2:  array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "9902" }  Product 3:   array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "9902" [1]=> string(2) "96" }   product 1 was purchased individually product 2 and 3 were purchased together

Comment: Modifications : Initialize the empty array before your Order Foreach instead of before order Item foreach. Updated Line :  $uniuqProductSkus = array();
foreach ($collection as $order) { //internal processing as it is}

Comment: that now duplicates everything a lot more?

Comment: here is the code i tested just now : $uniuqProductSkus = array();
foreach ($collection as $order) {
    $order_id = $order->getId();
    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id);
    $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach ($ordered_items as $item) {
        if (in_array($item->getProduct()->getSku(), $uniuqProductSkus)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            array_push($uniuqProductSkus, $item->getProduct()->getSku());
            // Do further echo here
        }
    }
}
print_r($uniuqProductSkus);

Answer (score 1):

How about [**array_unique()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) :

```
$ordered_items = array_unique($ordered_items);
```

Comment: I have tried that before and after foreach($ordered_items as $item){ but it doesn't work?

Comment: I think I maybe need to share more code as that won't work, full code above